# Proof Involving Integers and Modular Arithmetic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

> Prove that there do not exist two odd integers $a$ and $b$ with  $a\not\equiv b \pmod{4}$ such that $4\mid(3a+5b)$.

I'm using a proof by contradiction to show this, so i said: For the sake of contradiction, assume that there does exist two odd integers $a$ and $b$ with $a\equiv b \pmod{4}$ such that $4\nmid (3a+5b)$.

My question is, did I state the correct thing since i'm using contradiction? If so this is how I started:

$a$ being odd $\implies$ $a=2k_1+1$ for some $k_1\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$b$ being odd $\implies$ $b=2k_2+1$ for some $k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$.
multiplying $a$ with $3$ and $b$ with $5$, and summing both together gives us 
$$3(a)+5(b)=3(2k_1+1)+5(2k_2+1)=6k_1+10k_2+8$$
We can say $2(3k_1+5k_2+4)$, or $2k_3$, where $k_3=3k_1+5k_2+4$.
This shows us that $3a+5b=2k_3$ $\implies$ $2\mid 3a+5b$.

However, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You only have two cases to consider $a=1, b= -1$ and $a=-1, b = 1$ and then show that all other $a,b$ are either equivalent or not allowed by the constraints.

Comment: If you plan to use contradiction, you should actually assume that there exists two odd integers $a$ and $b$ with $a \not\equiv b \;(\operatorname{mod}\, 4)$ such that $4\mid(3a+5b)$. Try to do the proof by yourself in this case now. :)

Comment: @Suzet So we only pass on the negation to the existential quantifier and the part after "such that"?

Comment: The negation of the sentence "$\not\exists$ x such that $P(x)$" is "$\exists x$ such that $P(x)$". You don't touch to $P$ (your property). Think about it. The negation of "There is no human on Mars wearing a red T-shirt" is "There is a human on Mars wearing a red T-shirt", and not "There is a human on Mars not wearing a red T-shirt".

Comment: "My question is, did I state the correct thing since i'm using contradiction?"  I'm sorry to say not at all!  The opposite of "There do not exist things with conditions" is "There do exist things with conditions".  You did a double negative by "There do  exist things with the opposite conditions" is not at all contraditory.  Analogy.  Prove there do not exist any birds that don't lay eggs.  You assumed for contradiction there do exist birds that do lay eggs.  You will *never* get a contrary from that.

Comment: "So we only pass on the negation to the existential quantifier and the part after "such that""  Don't worry about rules so much as common sense.  The negation of "There do not exist things which ... blah...." is, of course, "There do exist things which .... blah....".  The statement "The do exist things which ... don't blah" not a contradiction!  In fact, its nearly a complete restatement of the original!  If there aren't any things that blah.... then of course there exist things that don't blah... *EVERYTHING* doesn't blah....

Comment: @Suzet Thank you! That was very clarifying!

Comment: @fleablood thank you too! I see what you guys are saying now. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach,
$$3(a)+5(b)=3(2k_1+1)+5(2k_2+1)=6k_1+10k_2+8=16k_1+10(k_2-k_1)+8.$$
It follows that if $4$ divides $3(a)+5(b)$ then $k_2-k_1$ should be even or $b-a=2(k_2-k_1)$ should be a multiple of $4$. Contradiction.

More briefly: note that 
$$3a+5b=4(a+b)+(b-a)$$
so $4$ divides $3a+5b$ if and only if $4$ divides $b-a$.
This implies that if $a\not\equiv b\pmod{4}$ then $4$ does not divide $3a+5b$. There is no need to assume that $a$ and $b$ are odd.